# Swift - Cocoa - Change window color?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to change the window color of my OSX app.

I am finding little information on how to do it, but I have seen some examples of it.

I have tried:

In my AppDelegate:
`NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black`
Which didn't work.

In my ViewController:
`self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue`

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you check the `mainWindow` or `window` is not nil?

Comment: `window` property will always be `nil` inside `viewDidLoad` method. Just override `viewWillAppear` method and move `view.window?.backgroundColor = .blue` there.

Comment: I spent like two hours. Maybe I am not searching in the right areas or for the right things? This is my first Mac App.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I am assuming you are using Storyboards here (because otherwise the template Xcode creates would have given you a `window` property in the `AppDelegate` and you'd probably would have successfully tried setting the background color on that).

There are many options how to do this but basically you would use an `NSWindow` subclass or an `NSWindowController` subclass to be responsible for setting the windows appearance (for those properties that can not be set in Interface Builder at least)

**NSWindow subclass:**

```
class BlackWindow: NSWindow {
    override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindow.StyleMask, backing backingStoreType: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: style, backing: backingStoreType, defer: flag)
        backgroundColor = .black
    }
}
```

and set this subclass as the class in the storyboard.

**NSWindowController subclass:**

```
class BlackWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        window?.backgroundColor = .black
        window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    }
}
```

and again set the class in the storyboard. There are many variants of where you can modify your window in the window controller, `windowDidLoad()` is just one suggestion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Btw no need to call super `super.windowDidLoad()`. "The default implementation does nothing" and NSWindow in your method signature is redundant `override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: StyleMask, backing backingStoreType: BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {`